# Exclude null inputs while concatenating JSON files

Tags: json, jq, trivy

I'm looking to concatenate multiple JSON files in a directory using jq.
Majority of the JSON files look like this

```
[
  {
    a: 12,
    b: 22,
    c: []
  }
]
```

So for concatenating them I use the follow jq query

```
jq -s '[.[]|.[ ]]' *.json > xyz.json
```

This seems work okay and I get the expected concatenated output until it encounters a JSON file that just has null written in it, and when I try to concatenate this with the others I get an error.

```
$ cat test.json
  null
$ jq -s '[.[]|.[ ]]' xyz.json test.json > y.json
jq: error (at test.json:0): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

Is there a way to exclude this null JSON file while concatenating through the directory?

I must mention these JSON files are generated as outputs for different **Trivy Image** scans and I have no control over what the output is.

If anyone else has faced this issue previously please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select array inputs.

```sh
jq -n '[inputs | arrays[]]' *.json
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/J6ELapSwyI)</sup>

Use `select(. != null)` instead of `arrays` if you don't want to exclude all non-arrays but only `null`.